# Extending @MainThread and @WorkerThread to validate specific threads

Tags: android, annotations

I want a selection of methods to only be run on a specific thread:

```
    new Thread("SpecificThread") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            sSpecificThreadHandler= new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
```

Is there any notation which would I be able to use? Such as `@WorkerThread(thread="SpecificThread")`

```
`@WorkerThread(thread="SpecificThread")`
public void doSomething() {

}
```

Comment: You could use EventBus to fire an event and deal with it in an  `onEventBackgroundThread(event)` method. Might at least be a small "subsolution" :)

Comment: But that does it on just any old background thread. I should be correctly calling these threads from within handlers, it's the validation I'm looking for rather than how to call them.

Answer (score -3):

use asynctask they are better than threads.

```
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

  }


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

  }


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {

  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

  }
 }
```

use like this:

```
new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
```

if you want async task to complete without moving forward than use **get** after **execute** method

Comment: Hi Burhan, Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I'm afraid that isn't a userful response to my question.